# What is Bootstrap logging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm exploring the serilog in asp.net core and come across the word bootstrap logging. I tried to find out more about it but there is nothing.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```

I got this syntax for initializing the bootstrap logger but didn't get the reason for using it.

Comment: Well, first result in a simple search using the named method: https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/

Comment: In a nutshell: Your "normal" application logging is configured and setup during App Startup together with all the other stuff. That means at that point, it is not yet "working". That's when "bootstrap logging" kicks in: You setup a rudimentary logging just to be able to catch (log) errors that happen _during_ that phase of application "booting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bootstrap logging** is a way for logging messages during the early phases of an application's startup, before the main logging infrastructure has been fully initialized.

The startup process in .NET Core applications includes various stages, such as **loading and initializing the program, establishing the application's dependencies, and configuring the logging infrastructure.** During these early phases, it may be required to log messages for diagnostic or troubleshooting purposes.

Bootstrap logging, which allows you to log messages to a temporary storage destination (such as the console or a memory buffer) before the main logging infrastructure is fully configured, is one approach to accomplish this. This is handy if you need to log messages before the application's dependencies are configured, or if you need to troubleshoot issues that may arise during the application's startup.